# Script running slow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, javascript, firefox

I have been getting the following error a few times today - any body else getting it?  Anybody know how to get rid of it?

> A script on this page may be busy, or
>   it may have stopped responding. You
>   can stop the script now, open the
>   script in the debugger, or let the
>   script continue.
>
> Script:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/content/js/master.js?v=3731:1

Comment: I get this error, as well. I believe it is related to Addblock Plus (version 1.1.3). The funny thing is: I don't recall installing Addblock Plus. I think it came with the last updated version of Firefox for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep having the same issue. I think it has something to do with a combination of the google analytics js and firebug / other add-in (Adblock Plus maybe). The two sites that give me this issue are netvibes and SO.
I have started to use chrome to browse SO ( & meta) as I need firebug and do not like enabling/disabling it all the time and anyway The issue seems to happen even with firebug in disabled mode.

Comment: I am trying now with firebug totally disabled (disabled the extension, not just "Disabled for all web pages") - will see what happens

Comment: seems to be working properly now - thanks for the heads up on FireBug.

Comment: I have had so many problems with FireBug being enabled that I have a seperate Firefox instance set up when I need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens to you in Google Chrome, let us know, otherwise (if Firefox) I strongly suspect add-ins.

You can also try running in Firefox safe mode which disables all add-ins as well.

edit: Firefox 3.5.x had severe issues with prettify.js that no other modern browser (Safari, Opera, IE, Chrome) did. Upgrading to Firefox 3.6 will fix the issue.

Comment: I'm running firefox 25 and still running into issues with prettify.js :( (not in this site though)

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar script error EVERY time I visit the SO homepage with IE8.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the error (or it's exact wording) as well as providing a list of the add-ins which you have installed?

Comment: The exact wording is in my earlier report of the same problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76230/ie8-warning-stop-running-this-script.