# Firefox freezes (script execution uses 100% cpu) upon trying to quote

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

I was trying to post a question on SO and when I select the "what" in the last sentence and press the quote button, FF freezes because of Script: stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/wmd.js?v=3297:1 which is taking too much time. I actually lost the question originally because my dom.max_script_run_time setting was set too high instead of the usual 10 seconds.

The text I'm trying to post is here: http://tinypaste.com/c2dfa

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate. Firebug causes the issue. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/script-running-slow). You could try one of the 1.5 [nightlies](http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.5X/) to see if the issue goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, just sometimes, the correct answer is: Don't use a RegEx for this.

Because regular expressions really don't like to search backwards :)

This will be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 0):

If this persists after disabling Firebug let us know. Specifically, if you can repro it in Chrome or IE8 let us know.

(I tried in FF 3.5.1 with your text and could not repro but I don't have Firebug enabled)

The latest Firebug versions are VERY VERY buggy.

Comment: I just tried on another machine running Windows 7 and Firefox 3.0.12 without Firebug installed - same freeze. I then tried on the same computer in IE8. Frozen as well (doesn't unfreeze like Firefox, cause IE doesn't have a script timeout). Make sure that when you paste that code into the description box for a new ticket, you then just highlight the word "what", and then press the Blockquote button.

Comment: I can reproduce it. FF 3.5.1, no Firebug. It appears even in safe mode.

Comment: The culprit are the quote signs ">". If you delete them, it works. The blockquote button has trouble, if these characters already exist in the text as it looks like.

Comment: Firebug isn't the culprit (or at least not the only culprit). I have a very similar problem on Chrome http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/bug-quoting-multiple-separate-blocks-sometimes-locks-up-the-browser-with-javascr

Comment: see my answer here for steps to reproduce: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60188/wmd-editor-bug-with-multiple-blockquote-blocks-example-on-cooking-stackexchange/64573#64573

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, redsquare,

I just tried on another machine running Windows 7 and Firefox 3.0.12 without Firebug installed - same freeze.

I then tried on the same computer in IE8. Frozen as well (doesn't unfreeze like Firefox, cause IE doesn't have a script timeout).

Make sure that when you paste that code into the description box for a new ticket, you then just highlight the word "what", and then press the Blockquote button.