# wmd.js looping when trying to quote test

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox freezes (script execution uses 100% cpu) upon trying to quote.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/firefox-freezes-script-execution-uses-100-cpu-upon-trying-to-quote)

> **Possibly Related** (but probably not):
>   [Firefox freezes (script execution uses 100% cpu) upon trying to quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/firefox-freezes-script-execution-uses-100-cpu-upon-trying-to-quote)

Under some circumstances (which I haven't been able to figure out) trying to quote some text using the *Quote* button in the bar will cause wmd.js to loop. It happens every time on every browser (so it's **not** related to firebug).

I'll post a test case as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[test](http://www.google.com)

> Testing,​
>
> test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test
>
> test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test 
>   test test test test test test test test test

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* Some code. Hi */
</script>
```

**trying to quote this will make the script loop.** [link](http://www.google.com)

Comment: I could not reproduce this (Chrome 4.0, Windows).  I tried quoting various permutations of the text in this answer.

Comment: @Micheal: you have to quote ONLY the line that says "quote this" (the last one). I reproduced it with chrome 4.0 on windows. Anyways jeff updated the other bug report (which turned out to be a duplicate after all) with status-reproduced

Comment: er - Ah yes, there it goes.  Fun.