# WMD editor bug with multiple blockquote blocks (example on cooking.stackexchange.com)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, blockquote

This may be a dupe (or sufficiently similar to) these 2: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/bug-quoting-multiple-separate-blocks-sometimes-locks-up-the-browser-with-javascr and [Firefox freezes (script execution uses 100% cpu) upon trying to quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/firefox-freezes-script-execution-uses-100-cpu-upon-trying-to-quote), but those are a year old and have no answer.

I posted [an answer on cooking.stackexchange.com](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/fruit-nut-allergy-cooking-for). (I presume the error still goes to this meta: please move it if I'm wrong).

In this answer I wanted multiple blockquotes. Whenever I tried to achieve this by just working in the edit box and using the blockquote button, my browser (tested in both IE and Chrome) would freeze up when I started the second blockquote. I worked around the problem by doing the thing in stages and with a notepad window open as well, so I got out the answer anyway, but that's obviously no good.

Comment: I really like the site design, but the bounty colors *absolutely* must be changed! (Green text on red button; one has got to go.)

Answer (score 1):

> You 
>   can
>   edit
>   this
>   answer
>   to
>   reproduce
>   the
>   bug.
>
> It 
>   seems
>   to
>   depend
>   on
>   the
>   number
>   of
>   lines,
>   not
>   words (you may need to add more if your machine is faster than mine).

**Don't** select this line

**Do** select this line and click on the blockquote button, you should get a script timeout.

*(Note, if you select both of the preceding lines, no bug)*